# Disable Browser Shortcut Keys

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to create, essentially, a 'kiosk'

I have an web application that I want to be the only thing accessible on screen.  I know chrome has a 'kiosk' mode (shortcut: chrome.exe --kiosk www.url.com).  That takes care of the auto-fullscreen, but disables very few shortcuts (perhaps only f11).

With a bit of help from the internet, I wrote out some javascript that gets *most* of the job done.  The code is as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.document.body.onkeydown = function() {
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            try {
                event.keyCode = 0; // this is a hack to capture ctrl+f ctrl+p etc
            }
            catch (event) {

            }
            return false;
        }
        return true; // for keys that weren't shortcuts (e.g. no ctrl) then the event is bubbled
    }
}
```

This takes care of things like ctrl+f, ctrl+p, etc.  Unfortunately, it does *not* disable shortcuts such at ctrl+t, ctrl+n, f5, etc.

Is it even possible to disable these, or am I chasing a rainbow here?  I don't care if it's javascript, settings, whatever, but I would really like to do it *without* a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable any keys you want via javascript. You just need to know the key code for them.

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is that something like ctrl+t or ctrl+n don't event send an event that JS can catch - it looks like it's immediately opening a new tab/window without the javascript even being able to do anything about it. But you ARE right regarding capturing F5 :) Thanks

Comment: From doing some googling it looks like you can intercept these in very new versions of chrome when Chrome is launched in app-mode.