# How to replace browser short keys defaults

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

According to some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656887/disable-browser-shortcut-keys) I find can out how to prevent a key  combination,
but I want to define a short key...

One way is to use `bind()` function in jQuery, and the problem is, keys default job is still working.   i.e: `Ctrl+s = savepage`

Any solution?

Comment: What else have you researched so far? Which browser(s) are you working with?

Comment: need a way for all major browsers, if there is...

Comment: Honestly, I prefer that my browser's keyboard shortcuts interfere with those from some websites than the opposite ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you linked isn't exactly what you were looking for, but the same concept can be used. Here's the jQuery equivalent only listening for Ctrl+s

```
$(document).on("keydown",function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent.ctrlKey && e.which == 83/*"s"*/) {
        setTimeout(function(){ //Fix for firefox. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860759/cant-override-ctrls-in-firefox-using-jquery-hotkeys
            // do save stuff...
            alert("Saved!"); // if you remove alert, you can remove setTimeout
        },0);
        return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SEQVD/3/

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: this is what I want... is there any tip for using `e.originalEvent.ctrlKey` Instead  of ctrl+s

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the events you've bind to a shortcut contain a preventDefault. In jquery this should look like:

```
function event(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Using other frameworks this could be different like `e.stop()` or `e.stopEvent()`.