# How can CTRL+S or ALT+S be set as a hot-key combination in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to set a 'hot key' for the Save button in an ASP.NET form. I wanted to use CTRL+S, but it seems to be the default Save 'hot key' for Windows. Is there a way to override that with my own implementation ?

Comment: ASP.NET is not relevant. You need to get it to work as a "hot key" (accelerator) for HTML in your chosen browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replace browser short keys defaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205150/how-to-replace-browser-short-keys-defaults)

Answer (score 4):

This is very possible in HTML/JS.  You need to assign an event handler to the element you want to "catch" the hotkeys, or event just the document as a whole.

It appears that if you use the `onkeydown` event, you can circumvent the default save prompt dialog in most browsers (At least IE, Chrome, FF).  I've not been able to do this using the `keypress` event for example.  So make sure to use the `onkeydown` event!

Example:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event)
{
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 83)
    {
        alert('You just pressed CTRL+S');
        // Do stuff here
    }
};
```

The next step is to perform the actual action you want to perform when the user presses CTRL-S.  Assuming this is a standard ASP.NET web form with a postback, you can programmatically post the form.

There are multiple ways to do that, this probably being the simplest (given the document only has one form!):

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

So the entire snippet would basically be:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event)
{
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 83)
    {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
};
```

**EDIT:  For multiple buttons, not just a single form submit, try something like this:**

Let's say that you have these asp:buttons:

```
<asp:button runat="server" id="btnSaveSubmit" onclick="btnSaveSubmit_click" Text="Save and submit" />
<asp:button runat="server" id="btnSaveHold" onclick="btnSaveHold_click" Text="Save and hold" />
```

Then your javascript would be something like this (Note, I'm assuming you are using jQuery now):

```
<script>
$(function() {
document.onkeydown = function(event)
{
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 83) //CTRL+S
    {
        // Just emulate a button click on the save and submit button by
        // using jQuery to find the button based on it's clientID
        $('#<%=btnSaveSubmit.ClientID%>').click();
    }

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 72) //CTRL+H
    {
        // Just emulate a button click on the save and hold button by
        // using jQuery to find the button based on it's clientID
        $('#<%=btnSaveHold.ClientID%>').click();
    }
};
});
</script>
```

That should do it ...

Comment: To extend the question - i have 3 buttons : 1) Save and submit, 2) Save and Hold, 3) Cancel. I need Ctrl+S to invoke Save and Submit, Ctrl+H to invoke Save and Hold. So it is not just a submit but invoking corresponding buttons.